# Using fragment tabs getting android.view.InflateException in Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, xml

Hello i am getting this exception while using Android 2.3.3:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

Exception fires in this method:
(When creating Fragment)

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (container == null) {
        // We have different layouts, and in one of them this
        // fragment's containing frame doesn't exist. The fragment
        // may still be created from its saved state, but there is
        // no reason to try to create its view hierarchy because it
        // won't be displayed. Note this is not needed -- we could
        // just run the code below, where we would create and return
        // the view hierarchy; it would just never be used.
        return null;
    }
    try {
        //exception here
        theLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return theLayout;
}
```

This happens when i go to Activity and return again to FragmentActivity and switch tabs.

What i should do for this one ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error (but I'm using MonoDroid and C#). In my case, I tried to inflate a layout that contains a `<fragment>` tag, but the OS (Android 2.3.3) doesn't know about fragments.

The solution for me was to use the Android Support Package v4 (android-support-v4.jar, can be found in `<android-sdk>/extras/android/support/v4` folder). I then created the fragment using the SupportingFragmentManager.

A description for MonoDroid with example code (that can be easily converted to Java) can be found here: http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Fragments/Part_4_-_Providing_Backwards_Compatibility_with_the_Android_Support_Package